# SAX parser crashes with "Permission Denied" exception message when retrieving google weather XML

Tags: android, sax, android-xml

I'm trying to get the current temperature via google weather with SAX Parser but I get a "permission denied" exception message when I try to get data:

Code:

> /* Get what user typed to the
>   EditText. */
>
> String cityParamString = ((EditText)
>   findViewById(R.id.edit_input)).getText().toString();
>
> String queryString =
>   "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather="+
>   cityParamString;
>
> /* Replace blanks with
>   HTML-Equivalent. */
>
> url = new URL(queryString.replace("
>   ", "%20"));
>
> /* Get a SAXParser from the
>   SAXPArserFactory. */
>
> SAXParserFactory spf =
>   SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
>
> SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
>
> /* Get the XMLReader of the
>   SAXParser we created. */
>
> XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
>
> /* Create a new ContentHandler and
>   apply it to the XML-Reader */
>
> GoogleWeatherHandler gwh = new
>   GoogleWeatherHandler();
>
> xr.setContentHandler(gwh);
>
> /* Parse the xml-data our URL-call
>   returned. */
>
> xr.parse(new
>   InputSource(url.openStream())); <----
>   THIS CRASHES WITH PERMISION DENIED
>   EXCEPTION MESSAGE

The url seems to be fine, but url.openstream doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add uses internet permission to your android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Been there done that :), been super frustrated

Answer (score 0):

Google maps is currently down in some parts of the world (if not all of it). Check Twitter for more info. There've been quite a few tweets in last few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As message suggests, HTTP request itself failed; nothing to do with XML parsing.

Comment: Ok, but why it fails? The url construction is correct and the url works if I paste to browser directly

Comment: I don't know; but you can test by reading contents first from URL into a buffer (using something like ByteArrayOutputStream) and seeing why it fails. And if not, can parse from ByteArrayInputStream built on contents that were buffered.